# Addon and Alias domains

Tags: alias

I understand that if I want an Alias domain is quite simple to do. cPanel>Domains>New and then enter the domain and click Share document root. Now when a user enters the new domain it will actually open your PRIMARY domain.
My quesiton is, what if I have 10 domains, and I want to create an alias for 1 of them, not being the main domain, would that be possible by simply entering the same root folder for said domain?

Example:

```
primary domain: 123.com directory /public_html
addon domains: 1234.com directory /1234.com/ 
abc.com 
abcd.com
```

In this example I want abcd to be an Alias for 1234 could that be achieve by simply sharing the 1234's folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. However, this does have ramifications if you are building sites that you want to have indexed by the search engines. If you have the same site visible under two different names, I have been led to believe that Google, at least, will decrease the ranking of both sites, making both sites harder to find from a search.